# Spring cloud dataflow's dashboard not found - 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

i'm trying to create a spring cloud dataflow server v2.10.3, but when i run the project i can't access the dashboard, it gives me an 404 error...

here is my main class :

```
@EnableDataFlowServer
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MainApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

here is a config class i added to overturn a security error :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Customize your security configuration here
    }
}
```

application.yml :

```
server:
  port: 9393
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      features:
        streams-enabled: false # works
        schedules-enabled: true #works
        tasks-enabled: true #works
  flyway:
    enabled: false
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    user: sa
    password:
    locations: classpath:db/migration
  datasource:
    password:
    username: sa
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    initialization-mode: never
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
  h2:
    console.enabled: true
    console.settings:
      web-allow-others: true
```

i tried to access the /dahsboard/index.html but it's not working, i expect to see the Spring Cloud Dataflow UI

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Dataflow is packaged and shipped and intended to run as an application already. Unless you are attempting to customize the server you simply need to run the executable jar. See [here](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/manual/) for more details on a local manual installation.